# Trying to get net.if.in and net.if.out values with zabbix api python

Tags: python, performance, monitoring, zabbix, network-traffic

I am coding a monitoring system using Zabbix API. First of all, I would like to explain the system I made. My program lists the hosts from Zabbix API every 30 seconds and collects some metrics of these hosts (such as cpu usage, disk, memory). I get this information via the item.get API call. I can easily obtain it. Finally, I need network traffic data such as net.if.in and net.if.out, but I cannot access these two metrics with item.get. There is no problem with the other information, I solved them, but I could not solve this one. I kindly ask for your support :)

I need to collect network traffic data via Zabbix API using Python programming language, but I cannot do this with the item.get API call.